# Как защититься от мультизапросов (Charles)?

Tags: php, sql, node.js

Приведу пример: допустим, нужно сделать чат, в котором отправка одного сообщения платная и составляет 1 рубль (первое условие). Второе условие заключается в том, что пользователю нельзя отправлять подряд более двух сообщений.

То есть, алгоритм отправки сообщения состоит в следующем:

1. Проверить, не отправил ли уже пользователь 2 сообщения, если отправил, выдать ошибку, иначе:
2. Снять средства с баланса (1 рубль), если средств недостаточно, выдать ошибку, если же достаточно, то:
3. Добавить сообщение в базу.

Проблема состоит в том, что при проверках запросы могут не успеть выполниться и пару запросов пройдет проверку и проскочит сквозь ограничения, пока старые запросы будут "заканчивать своё выполнение".

Данная ситуация лишь пример, и не стоит концентрироваться только на чате. 
Разберем пример с онлайн-рулеткой:

В одной комнате играет несколько пользователей (неважно количество). Лимит на сумму ставки -- от 10 до 50 рублей. Максимальное количество ставок за один раунд -- 5 ставок.

То есть, в данном примере также нужно сделать несколько проверок, чтобы потом добавить ставку в базу. Если ставка не успеет добавиться, а уже следующий запрос начнет выполняться, то в этом время проверка на количество ставок не будет пройдена корректно и лимит ставок может быть нарушен.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать в  этой ситуации?

Comment: Думаю стоит решать это на уровне БД. Включить транзакции. Если требуются некие проверки между получением изначения из БД и изменением БД, получать данные с блокировкой читаемых строк (например с помощью select for update, если ваша БД это позволяет). Блокировку явно снимать с помощью commit после того как выполнили все проверки. Так же можно постараться написать запросы так, что бы они принципиально не могли вызвать недостоверного состояния

Comment: Да, да, на рулетку это похоже на много больше  Казино экономят? или ищут свежие идеи по рестайлингу отжима денег? :)

Comment: @Mike а можно, пожалуйста, на примере? потому что никогда не работал с транзакциями, и хочется максимально правильно решить проблему сейчас. Понимаю, не всегда так получается, но всё же

Comment: В каждой СУБД это решается своим специфическим способом. И общие рекомендации дать невозможно. Вам надо изучить как работает механизм транзакций и блокировок в вашей СУБД и на основе этого знания уже разрабатывать конкретный алгоритм, решающий конкретную задачу. Но в общем виде блокируем запись, читаем, проверяем, пишем изменения в БД, снимаем блокировку (обычно автоматически по завершении транзакции)

Comment: Вот например первая задача решается вообще без всяких блокировок. Правда надо выяснить, что такое "подряд". Предположим что "подряд" это в один и тот же день. Тогда делаем на таблицу сообщений уникальный ключ по id_пользователя и дате сообщения. Делаем на эту же таблицу триггер, который при вставке сообщения списывает с баланса деньги (добавляет запись на списание средств, если конечно баланс ведется как сумма отдельных записей). После добавления записи списания, он же проверяет получившийся баланс, если меньше нуля - возвращаем ошибку, операция откатывается, целиком, включая сообщение.

Comment: А больше одного сообщения не позволит вставить уникальный ключ, ни при каких обстоятельствах

Comment: Но если баланс ведется как одна запись, например в таблице пользователей, то подход кардинально меняется, начинаем со списания средств в транзакции, это блокирует запись баланса и больше никто в это время уже не сможет ничего делать по этому пользователю, после этого уже можно спокойно считать сообщения, добавлять и т.п. Так что как видите, небольшой нюанс в архитектуре БД и подходы кардинально отличаются. Поэтому давать совет не под конкретную ситуацию с полным знанием архитектуры и других тонкостей в принципе невозможно